# PHP Uploading an image to server than cropping does n't show max file error

Tags: php, jquery

This code will upload the image to the server ,then user can crop the images.

http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/

In the code,maximum file size that you can upload is defined as 3 MB.When you upload a file which is more that 3 MB,it has to show this error to user "Images must be under ".$max_file."MB in size" But this code always shows Error!
Select an image for upload"

Is there any better plug in than this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @rlemon:I used the same code that is present in that link.Tried few things but did not work.It is not coming to this line if ($userfile_size > ($max_file*1048576)) {
   $error.= "Images must be under ".$max_file."MB in size";
   echo "imhere";
  } when image size is more than 3 MB.

Comment: @user1415759: Please stop begging for upvotes. That's not likely to get you any upvotes at all - it *is* a good way to get downvotes though.

Answer (score 0):

this is the latest link for uploading image not only for jpeg as  your link is only for the jpg image. Check this link -- http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop-v11/

Scroll down and grab this bundle as shown --

[image]

**PS--**

Check your image upload settings as well in `php.ini`

Comment: :i'm using ver 1.2,i get all this errors in this version only.

Comment: @user1415759 chk your image upload settings as well in php.ini